# Generating a 3D binary mask of geometric shapes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to generate a 3D binary mask which represents an ellipsoid with centers xc,yc,zc and radiuces xr,yr,zr.

I noticed that the function ellipsoid generates a mesh of points given these parameters. However, I want the data to be represented by a binary matrix (in my case, of size [100,100,100]), and not a mesh.

My Parameters are:

```
mask = zeros(100,100,100);
xc = 50; yc = 50; zc = 50;
xr = 15; yr = 15; zr = 15;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `myellipsoid = ellipsoid(50, 50, 50, 15, 15, 15);`, gives me a matrix

Comment: yes, but it's not the binary matrix which I was looking for. It's a Matrix which represents a part of a mesh. I need I binary mask of size 100x100x100 which contains this ellipsoid

Comment: Then please specify this more clearly in your OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a binary mask of shapes which can use an equation you can follow the steps:

- Generate a mesh (with `ndgrid`). Make sure the domain limits includes the volume/surface mask, and choose the mesh resolution according to your needs.
- Use the volume/surface equation to generate a binary mask, by doing a simple logical comparison of the coordinates with the equation.

---

### Simple 2D example:

Let's define a simple ellipse (in 2D).

```
%% // Simple 2D example
xc = 5 ; yc = 6 ; %// ellipse center = (5,6)
xr = 3 ; yr = 2 ; %// ellipse radiuses

xbase = linspace(0,10,11) ;         %// temporary variable used to send to "ndgrid"
[xm,ym] = ndgrid( xbase , xbase ) ; %// generate base mesh

mask = ( ((xm-xc).^2/(xr.^2)) + ((ym-yc).^2/(yr.^2)) <= 1 ) %// get binary mask
```

Gives you the binary mask:

```
mask =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Granted you can hardly recognise an ellipse in the mask but I kept the resolution low to be able to display it as text. You can easily increase the resolution by defining a finer mesh.

---

### 3D Ellipsoid:

Well, it's exactly the same method, except we are going to add one dimension to the mesh, and use the 3D equation of the ellipsoid. So for your precise case:

```
%% // 3D ellipsoid
xc = 50; yc = 50; zc = 50;
xr = 15; yr = 15; zr = 15;

xbase = linspace(1,100,100) ;
[xm,ym,zm] = ndgrid( xbase , xbase , xbase) ;

mask = ( ((xm-xc).^2/(xr.^2)) + ((ym-yc).^2/(yr.^2)) + ((zm-zc).^2/(zr.^2)) <= 1 ) ;
```

I cannot show you a text output with these kind of 3D arrays, but your `mask` is now a 3D logical array containing `true` inside the ellipsoid and `false` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Heaviside functions, this probably needs a bit more thought to get exactly what you want but as a start,

```
close all
clear all

%Setup Domain
maxdomain = 100;
mindomain = 0.;
step = 1.0;
X = mindomain:step:maxdomain; 
Y = mindomain:step:maxdomain; 
Z = mindomain:step:maxdomain;
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(X,Y,Z);

xc = 50; yc = 50; zc = 50;
xr = 15; yr = 15; zr = 15; 

r2 = xr/2;
r = sqrt((x-xc).^2/xr + (y-yc).^2/yr + (z-zc).^2/zr);
u =  heaviside(r-r2);

%Plot Surface of sphere
p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,u));
isonormals(x,y,z,u,p)
set(p,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');
camlight ; alpha(0.6);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
daspect([1,1,1]); view(3);
axis tight; camlight;  camlight(-80,-10);
lighting gouraud;
```

which for your values above looks like,
[image]

and for`xr = 15; yr = 45; zr = 15;`,

[image]

The Heaviside function can be defined using,

```
function [out]=heaviside(x)
    out=0.5.*(sign(x)+1.0);
end
```

if the Symbolic Math Toolbox is not available.

Comment: You should mention in your answer that the `heaviside` function requires the `Symbolic Math Toolbox` package.

Comment: true, although you can roll your own with the sign function: `function [out]=heaviside(x); out=0.5.*(sign(x)+1.0); end` which I think is generally available...

Comment: ha ha. True, the function is easy to reproduce. That is also something you could mention in your answer (in case they do not have the required toolbox). That would make your answer more generic and useful for a larger number of people ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
mask = zeros(100, 100, 100);

%//your ellipsoid properties
xc = 50; yc = 50; zc = 50;
xr = 15; yr = 15; zr = 15; 

for x=1:100
    for y=1:100
        for z=1:100
            if ( ((x-xc)/xr)*((x-xc)/xr) + ((y-yc)/yr)*((y-yc)/yr) + ((z-zc)/zr)*((z-zc)/zr) < 1 )
                mask(x,y,z) = 1; %//set elements within ellipsoid to 1
            end
        end
    end
end
```